# Hosting Server for Mobile App developed on Ionic Framwork with Couch/Pouch DB

Tags: android, couchdb, server, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I am developing an Android Application on Ionic framework and using Couch/Pouch DB. Can anyone suggest the hosting server on which I can host my application for best compatibility with the database.

Comment: You want to host your serverside module?

Comment: @Bhavesh yes i am looking for a hosting server provider with best compatibility with couch/pouch Db

Answer (score 2):

- [AngularJS wrapper for PouchDB](https://angular-pouchdb.github.io/angular-pouchdb/#/)
- [How to code your CouchDb and PouchDb replication](http://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html) for mobile or web apps.

#### CouchDb Hosting Services:

- [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/)
- [Iris Couch](https://www.iriscouch.com/)
- [Couchappy](https://www.couchappy.com/)

#### How to setup your own CouchDb hosting:

- [How To Install CouchDB and Futon on Ubuntu 12.04 - Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-couchdb-and-futon-on-ubuntu-12-04)
- [Secure CouchDB by using SSL/HTTPS](http://www.mircozeiss.com/secure-couchdb-by-using-ssl-https/)

#### Docker + CouchDb:

- [Dockerizing a CouchDB Service](https://docs.docker.com/examples/couchdb_data_volumes/)
- [GitHub: Yet Another Dockerized CouchDB](https://github.com/klaemo/docker-couchdb/)
- [Dockerized CouchDB 1.6.0 with stud SSL terminator](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/klaemo/couchdb-ssl/)

Answer (score 0):

Check This link for hosting couchdb

https://www.iriscouch.com/

iriscouch provide couchdb hosting on cloud.It is free till your monthly bill is below 5$.

it is cost you based on storage allocated by couchdb data, http read and write request.

your serverside data will be in iriscouch, and it is also providing security for access data.

iriscouch is best if you are thinking to go with couchdb.